# Have a Django backend on server. What steps do I need to take to move my Angular frontend there as well?

Tags: angularjs, django, rest

I have a Django backend on a Linux server with AWS. It is running with the built in Django web server.

I have also built a simple AngularJS frontend on my local machine. I created a simple AngularJS frontend from scratch. The solutions can't communicate because they are on different servers.

I would like to move my AngularJS solution to the same server. What steps do I need to take to move AngularJS to the same server and to get AngularJS and Django to communicate?

Answer (score 0):

1. The builtin Django web server ran with the command `python manage.py runserver` runs the Django backend locally so only local clients (with IP 127.0.0.1) can access it.
   To make it publicly available you need to run it with the command `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` it allows Django backend to be accessed on the network, on the port 8000. Also make sure you have opened the port. test this to see if you see any django views (assuming your server's IP is x.x.x.x use the address x.x.x.x:8000 in the browser).
2. I don't know if there already is an API implemented on your backend or not. I recommend django-rest-framework http://www.django-rest-framework.org
3. Now you have the API implemented by django-rest-framework and your Django backend is publicly available so you can communicate with it using Angular and Rest API with your server's public IP.

**PS:** If you wanted to put your frontend files on Django's static files directory you can follow the following documentation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

Comment: Thanks, I've got those 3 steps implemented now. Django is up and running. But how do I do the same for AngularJS - how do I put them on the server?